# currency regex with decimal

Tags: javascript, regex, currency

I need help: I want to validate in javascript my currency inputs that are in format:

`1 234,78` (so there is space between 1000 and 2 decimals that are possible).

Examples:

```
50,25
50
1 150
1 150,44
1 000 001
1 000 001,25
```

Can you help me?

Thanks2

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a good place to start learning regular expressions.

Comment: When spaces and commas are allowable characters in your input, you need some better way to separate distinct example.  Can you edit to put them on separate lines, place them in quotes, or put a clear separator character between them?

Comment: How many decimal digest are allowed? 1 or only 2?

Comment: 0,1 or 2 decimals are allowed

Comment: are leading zeros (e.g. `012`) allowed?

Comment: no. but nevagive values are. and 0 is allowed. 0,00 also.

Comment: The decimal divider is a period or a comma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^(\+|-)?(0|[1-9][0-9]{0,2}( [0-9]{3,3})*)(,[0-9]{1,2})?$`

Answer (score 1):

It is tested and it is going to work

example : 9 999 999 999,99

$('#amount').change(function() {

$( 'tr:last' ).find("td:last").text(messages['amount invalid']).hide();

```
var inputVal = $(this).val();   

var patternMontant = /^\$?(([0-9]{0,10}))?\,[0-9]{2}$/;

if(!patternMontant.test(inputVal)) {
```

$( 'tr:last' ).find("td:last").text(messages['amount invalid']).show().css("color","red");

```
 $(this).val('');
```

}

});

Answer (score 0):

I think something like ->

```
re.match(r"[0-9]{0,2}(\s[0-9]{3})*", str)
```

should work.

Comment: This doesn't account for commas.

Answer (score 0):

Use the autoNumeric plugin of jquery is very good and easy.
 plugin that automatically formats currency and numbers as you type on form inputs

First - include jQuery.js and autoNumeric-1.9.19.js javascript files in the header:

Second - insert a form and input field on the HTML/JSP document:

Third - in a separate script initialize autoNumeric $('selector').autoNumeric('init'):

jQuery(function($) {

```
  $('#someID_defaults').autoNumeric('init', {aSign:',', pSign:'£', vMax:'99999.99' });
```

});